# Парсинг нестандартного представления времени

Tags: php, время, datetime, парсер

Мне приходит время вот в таком формате

`$time='16:00:00/23:00:00';`

Нужно отдельно получить `16:00:00` и отдельно, то что после слеша `23:00:00`

Нагуглил как получить вторую часть:

```
date_format(date_create_from_format('H:i:s/H:i:s',$time),'H:i:s');
```

Выводит `23:00:00`.
Но как получить первую? Спасибо.

Comment: Не проще `explode('/', $time);` и обработать массив с часами?

Comment: @Other, не проще. Это костыль тогда

Comment: @RomanKozin, в смысле? Это время передавать так - костыль. А если нужен период - `explode` для этого и создан.

Comment: @Other, я еще сонный) Извините) Не так мозги восприняли

Comment: в таком формате период времени передаёт гугловский сервис api.ai, если же гугл уже передаёт данные как костыль, то что же тогда говорить о других?. Ок попробую использовать explode. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

```
date('d-m-Y',strtotime($_my_time));
```

`strtotime` преобразует Ваше время в некий объект для работы с временем и после, Вы уже сможете им манипулировать через `date` функцию.

В Вашем случае:

```
$time = explode('/', $time);
/** или **/
preg_match_all('~([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})~', $time, $results);

var_dump($time);
var_dump($results);
```

[Результаты регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/Tegfr5/1)

Comment: `strtotime` вернёт радостный `false` и парсить оттуда нечего: `var_dump(date('d-m-Y', strtotime('16:00:00/23:00:00'))); // string(10) "01-01-1970"`. Как и ожидалось.

Comment: @Other, сорян :) Еще не проснулся)